# want to add iframe in window apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winjs

I just want to add iframe in default.html  but it not working showing white page ...

Here my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FinderToday</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- FinderToday references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

    <p><a href="ms-appx:///page2.html">Go to page 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.bing.com">Search the web</a></p>

    <iframe src="http://maps.bing.com" style="width:1366px; height: 768px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser you are using to open this file "Defaul.html" ??

Comment: not in browser , in window metro apps

Comment: okay dear .follow this link hope this help ...   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7114e66e-4fcd-47e9-8d3d-339adbe3110b/correct-way-of-embedding-an-iframe-with-a-remote-website-in-a-metro-app?forum=winappswithhtml5

Comment: Does it work if you just try to host the web site in a standalone web page in the same way?

Comment: Most likely there is a script error in the iframe... Have you tried using a [`webview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx) instead?

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel Do you find your issue.? Iframe working fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Windows are you targeting - Windows 8 or Windows 8.1?

If you are targeting Windows 8.1, use the `x-ms-webview` element rather than `iframe`.

http://msdnstage.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx
http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/10/01/blending-apps-and-sites-with-the-html-x-ms-webview.aspx